# I try to design in android studio screen but , the screen became black and i don't know what's the reason

Tags: android-studio

I don't know what's the reasons every time i try to design the screen become black i cant do any thing ( i used android studio 2021 dolphin )

[image: 1]

i try to fix sdk tools and i done but i am not sure that the gradle file in its position in c desk

Comment: hey can you share your xml file code ? and I think there is some kind of missing attribute in your any of the views or layout used in your xml code.

Answer (score 0):

"One or more layouts are missing the layout_width or layout_height attributes" seems pretty intuitive, but if you still don't know how to fix that:

[image]

press on "Code" and copy all of the XML layout, then update your question with the code